# Acronyms.parse ([object].function) is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have a little chunk of code for transforming acronyms

```
var Acronyms = function () {};

Acronyms.prototype.parse = function(string) {
    var array = string.split(' ');
    var answer = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        answer += array[i][0];
    }
    return answer;
};

module.exports = Acronyms;
```

that when used with this test

```
describe('Acronyms are produced from', function(){
  it('title cased phrases', function() {
    expect(new Acronyms.parse('Portable Network Graphics')).toEqual('PNG');
  });
});
```

Gives me: TypeError: Acronyms.parse is not a function
When I tried to search for as many keywords as I could I kept seeing things about semi colons so maybe the issue is there? I don't think it is but maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Acronyms.parse()` attempts to get `Acronyms.parse` and use it as a constructor.

Instead, you want to use `Acronyms` as a constructor, and call the `parse` method of the instance. That can be achieved with

```
new Acronyms().parse() // preferred way
(new Acronyms).parse() // alternative
```

This is the reason it's not a good idea to omit the parentheses when instantiating a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate an `Acronyms` object using `new Acronyms()`, and *then* you can call `parse()`. As is, it's trying to use `Acronyms.parse` as the constructor, but that function doesn't exist (as it says) because `parse` is under the `prototype`.

Instead, use it like this:

```
new Acronyms().parse('Portable Network Graphics'))
```